# Best way to support light wrappers when restricting react components in children with flow

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

We have a list component that limits its children to list items. This works fine, but we're running into an issue where we need to wrap a child to add state or similar. In this case we run into flow errors. For now we've decided to just have the list accept `any` as children, but is there a better way to handle this case?

[simplified example](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiCWBbADrATgF1AFSgCGAzqAEoCmxAxvpNrGqAOTY32vK4CeGVUABkUpXAElcVNABV+ggLyJQoAD6g+A2JFABlFADsA5tCoiDVZWo3ztoACIBXYtHOXEmwQAUmGcgtAAbytaAAsUaAATDgMALkpOXAA6AFFTNCoDXAAeETFJaTkBAD5EAF9kWlgDMT1mKgBhaqkAD3wA6jpk2g5iKSasqjaACkCygEpkFURaaDJyJsxQIakDSPJO+iTFrAss7J9YP2KgqxjIqmxh8dOVFSqa-EDQMIjozNAy0ADccNIkjC+UhTO4cXCObAGUDDRAASFh2UiKAAbqU7qB4YFXlEYhUVPDssAkairCpJioKhUZnNSOR9MZTG5lm1MusEl1tsxdpkcmMTsEVOdLtdbqCqODIdC4QjicV6SZBG5CbLSaByZ9ypUaeQnC4mStWRtEpzMNUedk+aKhVcbgKxRKoTCCbLddBhIYqMqUWi7urKVr5qAAOrYYgYATYZmrNmbZI7M37S1260iu2C8UQx2qlTZXT1AatOPVUiODLYH3olSBYYPQs3BQnbKupmBJJt36iAFAr6ttu1lZfYDFPGVwl5jIFlacmqly4VtVWf3IIZYPCgC6QYiOaD4WaBgCC4ajhvZW3je15ZX5pJTttVYMzUoJO2K2RDYYjQ8JL9VfvKQA)

Answer (score 0):

So here's your error message:

```
Cannot create `Comp` element because in property `children.type`: Either `Wrapper` [1] is incompatible with `SingleLine` [2]. Or `Wrapper` [1] is incompatible with `DualLine` [3].
```

In other words, `Wrapper` does either not implement the same interface/class or is not an allowed type (in your ListItemType).

Wrap up: you've got the following classes:

```
type ListItemType =
  | typeof SingleLine
  | typeof DualLine

class SingleLine extends React.Component<{}>{}
class DualLine extends React.Component<{}>{}
class Wrapper extends React.Component<{}>{}
```

There are three options here:

1. extend your `type ListItemType` with the `Wrapper` type.
2. create an interface for all of your components (not quite sure how this works with react, but you basically inherit from a interface called e.g. `ListItemInterface`
3. let extend Wrapper from `SingleLine` or `DualLine` instead of React.Component<{}>